# HTTP authentication with POST

Tags: http, post

What is the correct practice to handle a POST request on that requires authentication?

Consider a client that going to POST some data to a location and does not know if that location requires authentication. Assuming the POST request has endless data and does not set a `Content-Length` header the server should read everything and then give a response (since giving back a 404 in the middle of the content would not correspond to the way how HTTP works if I understand everything correctly). But it simply can't because the content is endless. On the other hand the client could try an initial POST with no content and specify `Content-Length: 0` and then it would know if any authentication is needed. But if that is some kind of a single use location then with this fake request it is gone and needs to be regenerated.